# Python indexing explanation

Tags: python

I do not understand how the index goes through a loop in Python.

In this fairly simple code why does `del l[i+1]` gives an index out of bound error? Isn't the check taken care of by the while loop? How do you check to see if you are at the end of the loop?

```
def getString(str):
    l = list(str)
    i=0
    while i < len(l)-1 and i != len(l)-1:
        if l[i] == l[i+1]:
            del l[i]
            del l[i+1]
            i=0
            if len(l) == 0:
                print("Empty String")
                break
        else:
            i+=1
    print(l)

str = "aabbcc"
getString(str)
```

Comment: You can investigate your code with some more `print`s or e.g. http://pythontutor.com/. Note that, as with C++ and Java, the `while` condition isn't reevaluated *during* the body of the loop, so it's not clear why you expected different behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete `l[i]`, you shrink the list by one. If you *only* did `del l[i+1]` you'd be fine, or if you deleted in reverse order, you'd be fine, but deleting the earlier element first means you're effectively deleting element `i+2` (based on the original list at the beginning of that loop execution).

Simply flip-flopping to:

```
        del l[i+1]
        del l[i]
```

or slightly more efficiently deleting both elements at once:

```
        del l[i:i+2]
```

will fix the issue.

As illustration, consider `[1, 2]` (we'll assume your if check passes, I used different values to make it easier to understand). When `i` is `0`, you `del l[0]`, leaving `l` as `[2]`, then you `del l[1]` which is now past the end of the list. If you `del l[1]` first, you have `[1]`, and `del l[0]` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

[@ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42543542/39791) is correct. You can use python at the command line to see the difference:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 27 2016, 14:14:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> i=1
>>> del l[i]
>>> del l[i+1]
>>> l
[1, 3]   # note that we went one further because the list shrank
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> del l[i+1]
>>> del l[i]
>>> l
[1, 4]   # deleted adjacent items as expected
>>>
```